# Handlebars: sorting a list while keeping the original sort index

Tags: javascript, sorting, handlebars.js, helper

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adtk5se9/4/)

I want to display a list sorted, while also needing to know the original sort index (`org_index`).

How to do so?  Should I inject a new field in the array `sorted` in `.registerHelper('eachSort')`, eg: `[{'name':'b', 'org_index': 0}, ...`?

---

Js

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachSort', function(array, key, opts) {
  // requires: underscore
  var sorted = _.sortBy(array, function(item) {
    return item[key]
  });
  return Handlebars.helpers.each(sorted, opts);
});


var arr = [{'name':'b'}, {'name':'c'}, {'name':' a'}];
```

---

Template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="tpl-eachSort">
   {{#eachSort . 'name'}}
       name={{name}}=  / index_now={{@index}}= / index_org=?{{org_index}}= <br/>
   {{/eachSort}}        
</script>
```

---

Result

```
name= a= / index_now=0= / index_org=?= 
name=b= / index_now=1= / index_org=?= 
name=c= / index_now=2= / index_org=?=
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to reuse the default `each` helper, and since it's impossible to inject some functionality into it, you can embed the original index within the item iself, as you suggest. While the easiest, appending helper metadata directly into the data is not very clean.

helper

```
handlebars.registerHelper('eachSort', function(array, key, opts) {
    // append metadata into data
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i].originalIndex = i
    }
    // sort
    var sorted = _.sortBy(array, function(item) {
        return item[key]
    })
    // default each
    return handlebars.helpers.each(sorted, opts)
})
```

template

```
{{#eachSort . 'name'}}
name={{name}}=  / index_now={{@index}}= / index_org={{originalIndex}}= <br/>
{{/eachSort}}
```

A proper way would be to use the `@data` variables for this purpose. You can either skip the default `each` helper and roll it all manually, pretty straightforward.

helper

```
handlebars.registerHelper('eachSort', function(array, key, opts) {
    // zip for sorting
    var zipped = []
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        zipped.push({
            originalData: array[i],
            originalIndex: i
        })
    }
    // sort
    var sorted = _.sortBy(zipped, function(item) {
        return item.originalData[key]
    })
    // custom each
    var result = ''
    for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
        var item = sorted[i]
        // set metadata as @data variables
        opts.data.index = i
        opts.data.originalIndex = item.originalIndex
        result += opts.fn(item.originalData, opts)
    }
    return result
})
```

template

```
{{#eachSort . 'name'}}
name={{name}}=  / index_now={{@index}}= / index_org={{@originalIndex}}= <br/>
{{/eachSort}}
```

Or you can get more involved and use both `@data` variables and default `each` helper. Since it's possible to use functions as `@data` variables, you can register the `@originalIndex` data variable as a generator which will return the original indexes in sorted order one by one each time it's called:

```
handlebars.registerHelper('eachSort', function(array, key, opts) {
    // zip for sorting
    var zipped = []
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        zipped.push({
            originalData: array[i],
            originalIndex: i
        })
    }
    // sort
    var sorted = _.sortBy(zipped, function(item) {
        return item.originalData[key]
    })
    // separate sorted data
    var originalData = []
    var originalIndex = []
    for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
        var item = sorted[i]
        originalData.push(item.originalData)
        originalIndex.push(item.originalIndex)
    }
    // set original index metadata generator as @data variable
    opts.data.originalIndex = function() {
        return originalIndex.shift()
    }
    // default each
    return handlebars.helpers.each(originalData, opts)
})
```